# Tensor Product and Non-degenerate Pairing

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

In the proof of proposition 1.1 found in [this paper](http://www.math.harvard.edu/theses/senior/lee/lee.pdf), what is the rationale for the map 
$$
w^{\prime}\otimes (x\otimes w)\mapsto w^{\prime} \otimes v(x,w)
$$  found at the bottome of page 7?  Is it simply that you can always think of the tensor product as a bilinear map (i.e. v(x,w))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking of a tensor product as a bilinear form isn't quite right.  The tensor product $V \otimes W$ isn't the space of bilinear forms $V\times W \to k$, but rather its *dual* is. This is the defining universal property of tensor products.

If you read a couple lines up you have a map $ev_M: Z(M)\otimes Z(\bar{M}) \to k$, and $v: Z(M) \times Z(\bar{M})$ is the corresponding bilinear form.  Explicitly $v$ is the unique bilinear form on $Z(M)\times Z(\bar{M})$ sending $(x,w)$ to $ev_M(x \otimes w)$ for all $x \in Z(M)$ and $w \in Z(\bar{M})$.